# How to sort a list-like text in a cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, sorting, list

Suppose I have in a cell the following unsorted list-like text:

```
- VAL03
- VAL04
- VAL01
- VAL05
- VAL10
- VAL07
- VAL08
- VAL06
- VAL02
- VAL09
```

I would like to sort that list-like text. That is, in another cell I would like to get this:

```
- VAL01
- VAL02
- VAL03
- VAL04
- VAL05
- VAL06
- VAL07
- VAL08
- VAL09
- VAL10
```

How can I make that?

Note: I know the [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en) function but it seems to be useless for such a case.

Comment: In real life, do you need to do this for just *one* cell? Or will you need to have this done for a *range* of cells? And if the latter, does that range run vertically, horizontally or both? (I understand that each cell will contain a list, but I need to know the larger context.) For best chances of getting the requested help, share a link to a spreadsheet set up with some *realistic* data (which accurately portrays your real-world application in both type and range). For instance, will those leading dashes be there? If not, don't include them in your sample data, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my important comment to your original post. However, if I go only by what is included in your post (i.e., that there is *one* cell with alphanumeric data wherein all numeric portions are normalized to contain the same number of digits and where each element is separated by a line break), then the solution below will do what you want.

Suppose your original data is in A2. In some unused cell, place the following formula:

`=JOIN(CHAR(10),SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A2,CHAR(10)))))`

Comment: Pretty! I always learn a lot from you

Comment: If we are doing things right in life, we are each learning from everyone along the way.

Answer (score -1):

that type of list will sort normally with the "sort range A to Z" **Data's** submenu

The SORT() function works well with something like:

```
=Sort(A2:A,1,true)
```

Of course the sort will fail with values of 3 digits mixed with those that only have 2

Comment: The question is about the content in a cell, not in a range.

Comment: I apologize for not understanding the question correctly